# how to post back edited row only in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**I have two models as below**

```
public partial class provider_preapproval
{
public string encounter_type { get; set; }
public DateTime? e_start_date { get; set; }
public DateTime? e_end_date { get; set; }
public string status { get; set; }
public virtual IList<provider_diagnosis_dtls> provider_diagnosis_dtls { get; set; }
}

public partial class provider_diagnosis_dtls
{
    public string diagnosis_code { get; set; }
    public string diagnosis_desc { get; set; }
    public string diagnosis_level { get; set; }
}
```

**The view for the same is**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Preapprove", "Preapproval", FormMethod.Post)
{
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.encounter_type, htmlAttributes: new { id = "n", @class = "control-label" })                                                
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.encounter_type, (SelectList)@ViewBag.Encounter, "---Select Encounter Type ---", new { @class = "m-wrap " 
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.status, htmlAttributes: new { id = "n", @class = "control-label" })                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.status, new { id = "status", @Value = "New", @readonly = "readonly" })
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.e_start_date, htmlAttributes: new { id = "e_start", @class = "control-label " })                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.e_start_date, new { id = "start", @class = "m-wrap  ", @Value = @TempData["service_date"], @readonly = "readonly" })
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.e_end_date, htmlAttributes: new { id = "e_end", @class = "control-label " })                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.e_end_date, new { id = "end", @class = "m-wrap  datepicker", @Value = @TempData["service_date           

    //Template for dynamic generating row                         
   <table id="Newdiagnosis" style="display:none">
   <tr>
  <td><input  class="diag" style="width:200px" type="text"
       name="provider_diagnosis_dtls[#].diagnosis_code" value /></td>
  <td><input class="diag_desc" style="width:500px" type="text" 
       name="provider_diagnosis_dtls[#].diagnosis_desc" value /></td>
  <td>
 <input  type="text" name="provider_diagnosis_dtls[#].diagnosis_level)" 
   readonly value />
 <input type="hidden" name="provider_diagnosis_dtls.Index" value="%" /> 
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>

<table id="diagnosis" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    @if (Model != null)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.provider_diagnosis_dtls.Count; i++)
    {
    <tr>
     <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_code)</td>
     <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_desc)</td>
                                                                                                      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.provider_diagnosis_dtls[i].diagnosis_level, new { @Value = "Primary", @readonly = "readonly" })                                                <input type="hidden" name="m.provider_diagnosis_dtls.Index" value="@i" /> 
  </td>
  </tr>
    }
    </table>
    }
```

Rows to the table `diagnosis` is added dynamically on a button click.
Jquery used for the same.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#N").click(function () {

    var index = (new Date()).getTime();
    var clone = $('#Newdiagnosis').clone();
    clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/\[#\]/g, '[' + index + ']'));
    clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/"%"/g, '"' + index + '"'));
    var html = clone.html();
    $("#diagnosis").append(clone.html());

 });
```

and the rows are creating and while submitting the data is passing to controller and able to save in database.

Now I have to call back the posted details in the form with all the existing rows as `read only` means don't allow the user to edit the existing rows created earlier but we should allow the user to create dynamic rows on button click again.

Now my doubt is while submitting this edit form how I will identify the newly added rows, so that i can update the exiting details only with the newly added rows.

eg: Existing details in table.

```
Provider_Preapproval
Preapproval_id     encounter type    e_start_Date e_end_date Status
1                  01                2015-01-01   2015-01-01   s



  diagnosis_dtls

   dtl_id   preapproval_id code       desc      level
   1           1           M01       fever     Primary
   2           1           M2.1      headache  Secondary
```

Here both row in `diagnosis_dtl` table is related to the `preapproval` id `1`.

so when we click edit link it will pass the preapproval id 1 and will retrieve this details in read only mode.

now user can add more rows dynamically and add data but when submitting, only need to submit the newly added rows to the detail table with preapproval id as 1.
eg:
   user added a new row with following details

```
code       desc      level
 Z1        xxxx      secondary
```

this should come in `diagnosis_dec` table as below

```
detail_id   preapproval_id code       desc      level
     1           1           M01       fever     Primary
     2           1           M2.1      headache  Secondary
     3           1           Z1        xxx       Secondary
```

It is not necessary that dtl_id should be 3 because it is auto generating identity column.

I am stucked here. Please pour some light on this.

Signature of Post Method

```
public ActionResult Preapprove(provider_preapproval preapprove_dtl)
{

}
```

Comment: Why not just generate existing items using `DisplayFor()` so you just generate text (not form controls) so nothing posts back except the dynamically created new rows? Note also your template can be just a `<tr>` element (not a table) so you just add rows to the existing table instead of adding nested tables

Comment: Alternatively, `diagnosis_dtls` seems to have an ID property `dtl_id`, so if you have a hidden input for `dtl_id`, if its value is `0` then its new, otherwise its existing (assuming its typeof `int`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the reply..the first suggestion seems good..let me try..but for the second one the dtl_id is autogenerated column for that table (identity).

Comment: Exactly, its value will be zero for new items that have not been saved to the database. For existing items its value will be a number greater than zero so it should be easy to check if its new or existing.

Comment: @StephenMuecke :)  you are great..i didnt thought that much..let me try..will comment if succeed..need to refresh my brain..but with both suggestion it look first one is better solution..

Comment: The first is definitely better if you don't need to edit existing items (you don't waste band width posting back a whole lot of form data that you will never use).

Comment: @StephenMuecke yup..i will try the first method..thanks mate